# How can I distribute USB broadband internet connection over my LAN?

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, home-networking, ip, modem

I am using a wireless USB adapter with my PC (I have Windows XP installed). I want to distribute this USB network connection through the LAN card of my PC using a hub so that my three other friends (which are using Windows 7) can also use it on their laptops.

How can I do it? Should I use cross cables or straight one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be easy to use the "Internet Connection Sharing" feature of Windows XP to allow your friends to get onto the internet using your computer as a gateway.

If using a hub/switch you need straight UTP cables.